# JGit merge - read contents of conflicting files for merging manually in an external diff editor

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, jgit, git-fetch

Looking into controlling **git-pull** using **JGit** in the following manner -

1. use git-fetch and git-merge with setCommit=false (commit in dry-run mode).
2. if conflicts arise, read the conflicted files and show them in an external merge editor for (let's say, kdiff3) for manual merge.
3. continue the merge for non conflicting files (git-merge with setCommit=true)

**How can i access those conflicting files (a.k.a ours & theirs), or at least access their ObjectId ?**

here's an illustration

```java
oFetchCommand.call()
...
MergeCommand oMergeCommand = m_oGit.merge();
oMergeCommand.setCommit(false); // dry run 
MergeResult oMergeResult = oMergeCommand.call();
if (oMergeResult.getConflicts() != null)
{
  // ?
  // TODO - read the complete 'our' and 'their' files, 
  // show them in an external editor for manual merge. 
}
...
```

I guess that the optimal solution will be to get the ObjectId of the two conflicting files.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle your conflict file like this:

```
Map allConflicts = oMergeResult.getConflicts();
for (String file : allConflicts.keySet()) {
    //Call to your external merge tool (this suppose 
    //kdiff3 is in your PATH)
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = rt.exec("kdiff3" + file + "-m");
}
```

Comment: is there a way to fetch the ObjectId of the files ?, in case that i need to send them to another display component

Comment: You can fetch the objectID of merged commits (with includes both onflicting and non conflicting files), by `ObjectID[] objectsId = oMergeResult.getMergedCommits();` 
The conflicts files return by `String file=allConflicts.keySet()` can also be sent wherever you want

Answer (score 0):

To access the contents of a file within a specific commit, you need to resolve and parse the commit you are interested in, then use a `TreeWalk` to obtain the object-id of the file contents and finally use an `ObjectLoader` to access the content.

For example:

```java
// Skip the next three lines if you have a fully parse RevCommit at hand
RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk( repository );
RevCommit commit = revWalk.parseCommit( repository.resolve( commit-id ) );
revWalk.close();

String path = ... // repository-relative path to file
TreeWalk treeWalk = TreeWalk.forPath( repository, path, commit.getTree() );
ObjectId blodId = treeWalk.getObjectId( 0 ); // this is the objectId of the file
treeWalk.close();

ObjectLoader objectLoader = repository.open( blodId, Constants.OBJ_BLOB );
InputStream inputStream = objectLoader.openStream();
// use inputStream
inputStream.close();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
git checkout-index --stage=all -- $path
```

spits three temporary names holding the three indexed stages(1 2 3, base ours theirs).

```
git ls-files -us $path
```

lists unmerged paths and the indexed id's for the stages

Comment: Note that the question was about the JGit library, not about Git command line tool.